# Compile/Run EJB Code in NetBeans (Beginner)

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb-3.0, netbeans-7

I am very new to Java EE/EJB, with very little knowledge about it.

I have downloaded NetBeans (7.01) and GlassFish (3.01). But, as I have no idea about EJB, and am not getting how to run the code in NetBeans which includes a simple Stateless Session Bean, a JSP and some Servlets.

I found a nice example code [Calculator Example](http://www.roseindia.net/javabeans/calculatorsessionbean.shtml). Can any body help me by giving a step by step procedure how to run the NetBeans example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd advise you **not** to use the linked tutorial. It seems to be from 2011, but it still talks about a lot of deployment descriptors and home interfaces (which are old, bad, ugly and **unnecessary** nowadays).

You can refer to this [JBoss tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/) about EJB 3.0.

NetBeans have great support for Java EE development. Just a very fast tutorial (in Java EE 6):

**1. Create your EJB project (EJB Module)**

Create new project: `Shift + Ctrl + N` -> `Java EE` -> `EJB Module` -> `Next`. Choose whatever name suits you and hit `Next`. Choose the target application server (NetBeans should suggest you Glassfish Server 3.x) and Java EE version (choose Java EE 6) -> `Finish`.

**2. Add EJB to your project**

Now you have your EJB project created. Right click on the project name in `Projects` tab on the left hand side. Choose `New` -> `Session Bean`. Choose whatever name suits you, define your package and choose `Singleton` (if you're using EJB 3.0 you cannot create singleton EJBs - just choose another type). Make sure Local and Remote interfaces are **unchecked**. Hit `Finish`.

You've just created your first EJB ;-)

**3. Invoking EJB business method**

You can now try to use it. You need to execute your EJB class method - to do it, you'd need somebody to invoke your method. It can be i.e.:

- a servlet,
- a standalone client,
- a `@PostConstruct` method.

I'll show you how to use the last option which seems to be the easiest if you can use Singleton EJBs. All you need to know about `@PostConstruct` annotated method is that it will be invoked when the application container creates your bean. It's like a special type of the constructor.

The point is that you normally don't have any control over EJBs initialisation. However, if you used the `@Singleton` EJB, you can force the container to initialise your bean during the server startup. In this way, you'll know that your `@PostConstruct` method will be invoked during server startup.

At this point, you should have a code similar to the following one:

```
package your.package;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class NewSessionBean {

    // This method will be invoked upon server startup (@PostConstruct & @Startup)
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        int result = add(4, 5);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    // This is your business method.
    public int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

After running this exemplary code (big green arrow on the toolbar), you should see GlassFish logs similar to this one:

> INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB NewSessionBean :
>   [java:global/EJBModule1/NewSessionBean!sss.NewSessionBean,
>   java:global/EJBModule1/NewSessionBean]
>   **INFO: 9**
>   INFO: EJBModule1 was
>   successfully deployed in 78 milliseconds.

---

This example also shows another feature of the EJB 3.1 - right now, not only you don't need to use home interfaces but you don't even have to use any interfaces. You can just use your class directly.

Note that there are several things wrong with this example. You should not use `System.out.println` instructions, I've not used business interface but used `this` to invoke business method, I haven't used Servlets to invoke my EJB's business method and so on.
This is just a very simple example to let you to start EJB developing.

---

As requested, below you can find mini-tutorial for EJB<->Servlet<->JSP workflow:

**1. Create Web Project**

(Note: you could achieve the above example - with Singleton EJB - with Web Project as well. In this case we need Web Project as we'll create a servlet and JSP in one package.)

`Ctrl + Shift + N` -> `Java Web` -> `Web Application` -> `Next`. Set the name of your application -> `Next` -> the defaults are fine (remember the context path - you'll need it to access your application) -> `Finish`.

**2. Create your EJB**

In this time, it'll be stateless EJB as it betters reflects what the calculator bean should be.

You do it exactly as described above - just select `Stateless` instead of `Singleton` in the appropriate window.

**3. Put business logic into your EJB**

Find the example below:

```
package com.yourpckg;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

// Stateless EJB with LocalBean view (default when no interface is implementated)
@Stateless
public class Calculator {

    // Business method (public) that may be invoked by EJB clients
    public int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

**4. Create Servlet which will call your business logic**

RMB on your project or `Ctrl + N` -> `Web` -> `Servlet` -> `Next` -> define servlet name and its package -> `Next` -> define its URL pattern (remember it - you'll need it to access your servlet) -> `Finish`.

**5. Define dependency between your Servlet and EJB.**

Your controller (Servlet) need to use your EJB. You don't want to do any lookups or nasty boilerplate code. You just defines that your Servlet will use your `Calculator` EJB by using annotation.

```
@EJB
Calculator calculator;
```

You put this as a field in your servlet class, so it should be something like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    Calculator calculator;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...
}
```

**6. Put controller logic into your Servlet**

NetBeans by defaults delegates all HTTP Method requests into one method - `processRequest(-)`, so it's the only method you should modify.
Find the example below:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        // Fetch the user-sent parameters (operands)
        int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("operand1"));
        int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("operand2"));

        // Calculate the result of this operation
        int result = calculator.add(operand1, operand2);

        // Put the result as an attribute (JSP will use it)
        request.setAttribute("result", result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {            
        // We're translating Strings into Integers - we need to be careful...
        request.setAttribute("result", "ERROR. Not a number.");
    } finally {            

        // No matter what - dispatch the request back to the JSP to show the result.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("calculator.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**7. Create JSP file**

`Ctrl + N` on your project -> `Web` -> `JSP` -> `Next` -> type the file name (in my case its `calculator`, as the Servlet code uses this name (take a look at `getRequestDispatcher` part). Leave the folder input value empty. -> `Finish`.

**8. Fill JSP file with user interface code**

It should be a simple form which defines two parameters: `operand1` and `operand2` and pushes the request to your servlet URL mapping. In my case its something like the following:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="MyServlet">
            <input type="text" name="operand1" size="3" value="${param['operand1']}" /> +
            <input type="text" name="operand2" size="3" value="${param['operand2']}" /> = 
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
        </form>

        <div style="color: #00c; text-align: center; font-size: 20pt;">${result}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just watch the form `action` attribute value (it should be your Servlet URL mapping.).

1. Enter your application

You should know what port your GlassFish uses. I guess that in NetBeans by default its `37663`. Next thing is the Web Application URL and JSP file name. Combine it all together and you should have something like:

> http://localhost:37663/MyWebApp/calculator.jsp

In two input texts you type the operands and after clicking 'Calculate' you should see the result.

Comment: Please give me a sign if you have a problem with EJB <-> Servlets connection and you already have working EJBs.

Comment: @alessandro are you **sure** that you need to go to EJB 2.x world? Are you **sure** and willing to enter this god-forgotten land? ;-) Before answering, you should know that "home interface" is not required for connecting EJB with Servlets. It's just EJB 2.x way of accessing your beans. I will shortly update my answer with Servlets and JSP using this EJB.

Comment: You can check the updated answer. You should now know how to use these tree concepts. This uses no-interface views (LocalBeans) which are EJB 3.1 feature. For remote and home interfaces I'll guess you'll need to google a bit :-)

Comment: Here is a more detailed guide ->[Steps for creating Enterprise Application in Netbeans IDE](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwqMhWCciGmITnRHcXFXMVM3NDA). I also made a video following this answer and other resources that I found on the internet ->[Create Enterprise Application in NetBeans. (ejb,servlet,jsp)](http://youtu.be/490uvFPbnA0)